# Search and move files to another folder with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Maybe someone can help me.

I am looking for a vba code thats searches in a folder for kewords of the filename, and then moves these found files to anthor folder.

The keywords are stored in column A in excel.

I have used the following code and it works partly. The problem is that column A has to contain the exact filename in the following code. I want vba to search for keywords. The other thing is that the files have to be moved instead of been copied. And if a file has been moved that there is check in column B.

```
Sub Test()

Dim R As Range, r1 As Range
Dim SourcePath As String, DestPath As String, FName As String

SourcePath = "C:\Downloads\"
DestPath = "C:\Downloads\New folder\"
Set r1 = Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each R In r1
FName = Dir(SourcePath & R)

 Do While FName <> ""

   If Application.CountIf(r1, FName) Then
      FileCopy SourcePath & FName, DestPath & FName

     R.Offset(0, 1).Value = FName

  Else

     MsgBox "Bad file: " & FName & " ==>" & FName & "<== "

  End If

   FName = Dir()
 Loop
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and where do you get stuck?

Comment: Hi Alex, See my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcards in the `Dir` function if your range only contains keywords of the file. Like this:

`FName = Dir(SourcePath & "*" & R.Value & "*")`

It will then process all files where this keyword is used in.

Comment: I have tested your code, i get bad file message with the filenames corresponding with the keywords in column A been used. Its only working when using full filename in column A.

Comment: That is because of the if-statement and the countif function. There you check if the filename is in column A, but it isn't of course because column A only contains keywords.

Comment: Yes indeed. I have deleted the if statement. The code runs as it should be. Thanks!